# How can I use my php in Twig (custom controller?)

Tags: php, html, controller, twig

I have a bit of a problem. I'm making a website for a basketbal club, in this website there's a page for each team and within this page there are two div's(lets just say one, i know how to do things twice :)). This div is filled with information that I get from a JSON and is put into a table. I had a working code for this, but now I have my website within the php framework Twig. Now the code doesn't work anymore. I've heard from my teacher that I have to make a custom controller for twig. What is this, and how do I do this?

PHP CODE :

```
<?php
function getTableC($link)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($link);
    $data = json_decode($json);



    if (count($data->wedstrijden)) {
        // Open the table
        echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered\">
            <tr>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Tijd</th>
                <th>Thuis</th>
                <th>Uit</th>
                <th>Uitslag</th>
            </tr>";


            //Cycle through the array
            foreach ($data->wedstrijden as $idx => $wedstrijden) {
                $arrDate = explode(' ', $wedstrijden->datum);
                $arrTime = explode(':', $arrDate[1]);
                // Output a row
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$arrDate[0]</td>";
                echo "<td>$arrTime[0]:$arrTime[1]</td>";
                echo "<td>$wedstrijden->thuis_ploeg</td>";
                echo "<td>$wedstrijden->uit_ploeg</td>";
                echo "<td>$wedstrijden->score_thuis - $wedstrijden->score_uit</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }



        // Close the table
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Edit 1:
I used to use this to include the php code :

```
<!-- Content Text-->
<div class="panel-box">
<div class="titles">
    <h4>Aankomende Wedstrijden</h4>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="standtable">
        <?php include("php/competitie.php"); echo getTableC("http://west.basketball.nl/db/json/wedstrijd.pl?cmp_ID=411&plg_ID=10845"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would tell more about the context where you are using twig I could give you a more specific answer.

Twig enables you to put the functionality, e.g. to iterate over your array, inside your template.

What basically should happen, when your php code is executed, is that you collect all the needed data and pass it to your twig template. Then twig renders your page.

Starting from your code this could look like this on the php side. Specifics depend on whether you are using a framework like symfony. The following assumes that you are using flat php without a framework (also take a look at the [twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html)):

```
 function renderPage($link)
 {
    // twig stuff
    require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
    Twig_Autoloader::register();
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
    ));

    // get your data
    $json = file_get_contents($link);
    $data = json_decode($json);

    echo $twig->render('table.html', array('tableData' => $data->wedstrijden));
}
```

And the template `table.html`:

```
...
    <!-- Content Text-->
    <div class="panel-box">
    <div class="titles">
        <h4>Aankomende Wedstrijden</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="standtable">
{# here the table is built #}
{% if tableData is not empty %}
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Tijd</th>
            <th>Thuis</th>
            <th>Uit</th>
            <th>Uitslag</th>
        </tr>
    {% for row in tableData %}
        {% set aDate = row.datum|split(' ') %}
        {% set aTime = aDate[1]|split(':') %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ aDate[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ aTime[0] }}:{{ aTime[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.thuis_ploeg }}</td>
            <!-- ... and so on -->
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}

        </div>
    </div>
...
```